# Designing an ElasticSearch query with cummulative filters, but with "OR" condition for the options inside the filter

Tags: elasticsearch, match

I'm trying to write an ElasticSearch query to search for contacts in an index. The user has the option to write a search term and also select from a couple of filters.

Everything is working fine except for `custom_field_1` and `custom_field_2`. These are custom filters that user can define and can have one or many possible options to select from.

I want to design the query so that these custom filters have an `AND` relation with other filters and an `OR` relation for the selected options inside the filter.

Basically, if the user has selected `foo` and `bar` from the `custom_field_1` and `blah` for the `custom_field_2`, the query needs to find records that contain either `foo` or `bar` and must contain `blah`.

What I have so far is this, but it's not delivering the expected results:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "john",
            "type": "cross_fields",
            "fields": [
              "first_name",
              "last_name",
              "username",
              "email"
            ],
            "operator": "and"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "custom_field_1": {
                    "query": "foo"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "custom_field_1": {
                    "query": "bar"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "custom_field_2": {
                    "query": "blah"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "status": [
                    "new",
                    "contacted",
                    "offer",
                    "contract"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "updated_at"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "user_id": 357
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "created_at": {
              "gte": "2021-05-01 00:00:00",
              "lte": "2021-05-31 23:59:59"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Terms Query for custom_field_1 and custom_field_2.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "john",
            "type": "cross_fields",
            "fields": [
              "first_name",
              "last_name",
              "username",
              "email"
            ],
            "operator": "and"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "custom_field_1": ["foo", "bar"]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "custom_field_2": ["blah"]
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user_id": 357
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "created_at": {
              "gte": "2021-05-01 00:00:00",
              "lte": "2021-05-31 23:59:59"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
            {
                "terms": {
                    "status": [
                        "new",
                        "contacted",
                        "offer",
                        "contract"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "updated_at"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Using `terms` seems to do the job.